# Possible to use mixins in function based views?

Tags: django, django-views

Like the title states, I'm wondering if it's possible to use mixins in a function based view. If so, how would I import it? The following code doesn't work:

```
def payment_method_view(request, MyMixin):
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, usually then you use *decorators*. Now you defined a parameter, that (according to Python) only happens to have the same name as a certain class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**.

First of all, it makes **no sense**. A mixin is something to *mix* into a *class*. You "*patch*" certain functions in a mixin. But how would you do that on a function? A function can have attributes, but the idea is that typically a function does not do much with its attributes. It typically has no workflow where it calls attached functions. If you would be able to apply a mixin, that would mean that all of a sudden your function for example has a `payment_method_view.get_queryset` function. Although that could perhaps be useful, this is not really how functions are designed to be used.

A function typically encodes a form of computation, it is typically not used as some sort of collection that stores named attributes that interact with each other. A class is typically used for that: it contains elements (class attributes and methods), and they can interact with each other.

But furthermore it would result in a lot of problems. A function has no *builtin* inheritance mechanisms. So it means that if you applied to mixins that patched a function, then there would not be some *method resolution order (MRO)* that will "*guide*" `super()` calls, etc. As a result, very easily this would break.

Syntactically it makes no sense either. You simply defined a function that takes two parameters: `request`, and `MyMixin`. The fact that `MyMixin` happens to be the name of a class, is - according to Python - a coincidence. Function parameters define a scope, so it means that if you would use `MyMixin` in the function, you would refer to the value that corresponds to the given parameter.

What you typically do to change a function, is writing a **decorator**. A decorator is a function that takes as input the function, and alters the function, or creates a new one. In that case the *decorated function* is used. For example we can make a decorator `@login_required`:

```
from functools import wraps

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def g(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.user.is_authenticated():
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
    return g
```

Here we thus have defined a function `login_required` that takes as input a function `f`, and we construct a new function `g`. This function takes as parameters `request`, `*args` and `**kwargs`. First `g` checks if the user that is attached to the `request` is autheticated (has logged in), if that is the case, we call the given function `f` with the `request`, `*args`, and `**kwargs`. If not, we return a 401 exception (not autheticated).

Now we can apply our decorator to a function:

```
@login_required
def payment_method_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

So now Python will call our `login_required` function with `payment_method_view` as parameter, and the result (the `g` function) will take the place of the `payment_method_view`. We thus now require the user to be logged in before the *original* `payment_method_view` is called.

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I saw you most of the time on stackoverflow U  always give simple and nice explanation of anything. Thank you